# I did not receive the association bonus

Tags: support, association-bonus

I have joined the Meta Stack Exchange community. Although I have not received any [bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

How can I get the bonus?

Comment: What made you think you should get the bonus?

Answer (score 9):

As the page you linked to says:

> If you are an experienced Stack Exchange network user with 200 or more reputation on at least one site, you will receive a starting +100 reputation bonus to get you past basic new user restrictions.

You do not currently have 200 or more reputation on any site.